# Convert value while inserting into HIVE table

Tags: hadoop, hive, hadoop-partitioning

i have created bucketed table called **emp_bucket** into 4 buckets clustered on salary column. The structure of the table is as below:

```
hive> describe Consultant_Table_Bucket;
OK
id                      int                                         
age                     int                                         
gender                  string                                      
role                    string                                      
salary                  double                                      
Time taken: 0.069 seconds, Fetched: 5 row(s)
```

I also have a staging table from where i can insert data into the above bucketed table. Below is the sample data in the staging table:

```
id      age     Gender   role         salary
-----------------------------------------------------
938     38      F       consultant      55038.0
939     26      F       student 33319.0
941     20      M       student 97229.0
942     48      F       consultant       78209.0
943     22      M       consultant 77841.0
```

My requirement is to load data into the bucketed table for those employees whose salary is greater than 10,000 and while loading i have to convert ***"consultant"* role** to **BigData consultant** role.

I know how to insert data into my bucketed table using the select command, but need some guidance how can the **consultant** value in the role column above can be changed to **BigData consultant** while inserting.

Any help appreciated

Comment: Replace your column selection during insertion with a CASE statement. Saying, if it's a consultant, then insert the other value instead

Comment: If you show what `insert` statement you already wrote it will be easier to help you.

Comment: @Guillaume Below is my insert statement

```INSERT TABLE bucketed_user PARTITION (salary) select id, age,gender,role,salary FROM stage_table where salary > 10000```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your `insert`, you just need to work on the `role` part of your `select`:

```
INSERT into TABLE bucketed_user PARTITION (salary)
select
    id
  , age
  , gender
  , if(role='consultant', 'BigData consultant', role) as role
  , salary
FROM
  stage_table
where
  salary > 10000
;
```

Comment: this is the great info, i was looking for